# Variable does not pass dictionary key:values properly while "harcoding" does

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am reaching out because I am facing a problem with dictionary key & values. The code below is used as followed:

1. We generate a dictionary from a csv file (the dictionary is called `prediction_dict`)
2. We generate another dictionary that is identical called `prediction_dict_backup`
3. Then we create a function that is going to "cut" some specific rows of the dictionary based on some specific value thresholds given by elo & prob values
4. Then we run the function through a couple of nested loops of elo & prob values

Every time an iteration of the loop ends, I want to reset my dicitonary key & values (i.e. restore the same dictionary before cutting the rows with the function).

```
#Import modules
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import csv
import collections

#Import local data & transform in DataFrame tables
read_invest_set = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\rapha\\Desktop\\10Milz\\5. Python\\CSV\\18.04.2020 [CSV] INVEST DB PYTHONV1.csv', sep=";")
invest_set = pd.DataFrame(read_invest_set)

#Set colmuns values as lists for loops
outcome = invest_set['outcome'].values.tolist()
expected_roi = invest_set['roi_expectancy'].values.tolist()
probs = invest_set['probability'].values.tolist()
elos = invest_set['elo_surface_player1'].values.tolist()
odds = invest_set['player1_odds'].values.tolist()

prediction_dict = {}
prediction_dict_backup = {}
scenarios = {}

for i in range (0,len(outcome)-1):
    game = {}
    game['roi_expectancy'] = expected_roi[i]
    game['elo_surface_player1'] = elos[i]
    game['probability'] = probs[i]
    game['player1_odds'] = odds[i]
    game['outcome'] = outcome[i]

    prediction_dict[i] = game
    prediction_dict_backup[i] = game

def simulation_engine(elo, prob, prediction_dict):

    scenario = "elo_surface_player1: {} & probability: {}".format(elo,prob)
    scenarios[scenario] = {}

    for i in list(prediction_dict):
        if prediction_dict[i]['elo_surface_player1'] < elo:
            del prediction_dict[i]

    for i in list(prediction_dict):
        if prediction_dict[i]['probability'] < prob:
            del prediction_dict[i]  

    for i in list(prediction_dict):
        if prediction_dict[i]['roi_expectancy'] < 1:
            del prediction_dict[i]  

    success_count = 0
    loss_count = 0 


    for i in prediction_dict:        

        if prediction_dict[i]['outcome'] == 1:
            success_count += 1
        else:
            loss_count += 1

#Demo thresholds to avoid running the program on large files
elo_scores_test = [2091,2262,1812]
prob_tests = [0.6,0.8,0.95]

#Loop through each pair of [elo,prob] scenario to generate the betting outcome & assess strategy value    
for elo in elo_scores_test:
    for prob in prob_tests:
        total_games,success_rate,overall_roi,avg_roi_bet = simulation_engine(elo, prob, prediction_dict)
        prediction_dict = prediction_dict_backup
```

Here is the deal. When setting the value of prediction_dict = to the backup dictionary, it does not work. By comparison, if I "hardcode" the values in the dictionary, then it is properly restored (see a sample of the hardcoded dictionary below):

```
prediction_dict = {318: {'roi_expectancy': 1.1, 'elo_surface_player1': 2457, 'probability': 1.0, 'player1_odds': 1.1, 'outcome': 1}, 319: {'roi_expectancy': 1.1, 'elo_surface_player1': 1982, 'probability': 1.0, 'player1_odds': 1.07, 'outcome': 1}, 320: {'roi_expectancy': 1.1, 'elo_surface_player1': 2534, 'probability': 1.0, 'player1_odds': 1.04, 'outcome': 1}, 321: {'roi_expectancy': 0.99, 'elo_surface_player1': 2059, 'probability': 0.9, 'player1_odds': 1.1, 'outcome': 1}}
```

I do not quite understand why the "hardcoded" value do work in this situation and why using my backup dictionary does not here. Does anyone has some tips?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Because `prediction_dict = prediction_dict_backup` just makes the name `prediction_dict` refer to the *same object* as `prediction_dict_backup`, this is how assignment **always works**. In other words, **assignment never copies**. When you use a literal, it creates *a new object*. See: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because both `dict`s are essentially the same variable in your case.

You need to make a copy like this:

```
import copy

prediction_dict = {}

for i in range (0,len(outcome)-1):
    # loop elided

prediction_dict_backup = copy.deepcopy(prediction_dict)

# then later inside your loop:
    prediction_dict = copy.deepcopy(prediction_dict_backup)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the explanation, clearly I wouldn't have invented this one.

Comment: Just make sure you read up on the mandatory link to ned batchelder.